# How to get special file offest in zip using java

Tags: java, android, python, zip

I use `ZipEntry` and `ZipInputStream` and `ZipFile` in java to get some information of zip archive. But still I cannot get one information.

Python can do like this：

```
otazip = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], 'r')
load_info = otazip.getinfo('load.bin')
load_offset = load_info.header_offset + len(load_info.FileHeader())
```

Can anyone help me to get the `load_offset`using java like python does？

Comment: IMHO, This is what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872455/reading-files-from-an-embedded-zip-archive

Comment: I want to get the location of the load.bin payload within the zip archtive.the link seems to be about reading file in zip archtive？

Comment: I found a solution from the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046951/how-can-i-find-the-file-offset-of-a-zipfile-entry-in-java

Comment: the link helps me too：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372759/android-get-compressed-size-of-a-file-in-a-zipfile/12372798#12372798

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is no method to get offset from ZipEntry.

I tried below solution and it's working fine for me:

```
  public long getZipEntryOffset() {
       String path = ota.zip;
       final String loadString = "load.bin";
       long offset = 0;
       File zipFile = new File(path);
       ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));

      try { 

        ZipEntry loadEntry = zisp.getNextEntry();
        while( loadEntry != null){
        long fileSize = 0;
        long extra = loadEntry.getExtra() == null ? 0 : loadEntry.getExtra().length;
        String fileName = loadEntry.getName();
        Offset += 30 + loadEntry.getName().length() + extra;
        if(!loadEntry.isDirectory()){
                fileSize = loadEntry.getCompressedSize();
        }    

        if (fileName.equals(loadString )) {
         loadSize = loadEntry.getSize();
         break;
        }
        offset += fileSize;
        loadEntry = zisp.getNextEntry();
    }

   zisp.closeEntry();

 }finally {
    zis.close();
}

  return offset ;
}
```

The offset is comprised of 30 bytes of standard zip header info + the file name length + some possible extra OS-specific flags + the data itself